# How to detect the encoding of a PPTX file?

Tags: java, http-post, apache-poi

My question is, *how can I get the encoding of a pptx file in Java?*
(I'm using apache poi)

```
   File f = new File(filename);
   XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream(f));
```

The reason why I need to know the encoing is that later on, I post some data of the file which I have saved in a json string and It is at this stage my problem occurs.

When doing a http POST the encoding is changed, and I figured this problem could be solved If I knew the encoding of the data in my json string. Then I could set this encoding in my http POST.

**EDIT/CLARIFICATION:**

The problem is the swedish letters å,ä and ö.

å becomes Ã¥

ä becomes Ã¤

ö becomes Ã¶

Comment: Could you show the code (or a simple example) that does the json post? I have a suspicion that the input from the file is fine but that you're posting the wrong thing in your next step - I've struggled with encodings a lot myself until I realized that Java Strings aren't stored internally as UTF-8, they're UTF-16 (I think). In order to send them somewhere else you'll have to do ``myString.getBytes("UTF-8")`` instead.

Comment: @Antares42 You still seem to struggle with encodings. Here's a very good article that'll shed the light on charsets, encodings and everything in between: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

Java and POI aside, to get to the encoding of a PowerPoint PPTX file, you have to examine the underlying XML for the slides:

1. Unzip the pptx file (for manually looking, any zip utility like 7-zip will do).
2. Under the zip root, find the ppt/slides directory.
3. Typically each slide is slide#.xml; open the one you want to examine.
4. Read the first line:  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`

In most cases, I would expect the encoding to be the same across all slides (meaning that you could probably use the root-level "[Content_Types].xml" file as a proxy for encoding of the entire archive).